# How to get the http request of an app with android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, httprequest

I have an android app which sends the http requests. I want to get the link of the http request using android studio.

Is it even possible? Is there any other way to get it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have code ... check the connection link in code/raw/strings

Comment: This is not my app. This is the app that i downloaded from the playstore.

Comment: ok tell me the app name

Comment: app link is here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hamropatro

Comment: you mean you want the code of this app?

Comment: I mean to track the Http requests sent by any app.

Comment: @all: I have updated the question to be more precise. Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43444/listen-which-urls-an-app-tries-to-connect

Comment: Is there any specific reason on why you would want to do this from within Android studio?

Comment: @Ramnath : No but preferred. Any technologies are welcomed.